# NN Backpropagation: Computing $\frac{{\rm d}E }{{\rm d}y}$.

Tags: partial-derivative, neural-networks

I would appreciate some help on the following problem: I'm taking Hinton's coursera class on Neural Nets and I'm not sure I understand the step highlighted in the picture (see below).

[image]

**Background:**

- $i$ is hidden layer
- $j$ is the top layer
- Neurons use logistic regression as their activation function

**What I understand:**
The chain rule allows you to "break down" the partial derivative and introduce a term that is helpful for your calculation:

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial y_i}=\frac{\partial E}{\partial z_j}\cdot\frac{\partial z_j}{\partial y_i}$$

**What I don't understand:**
Where does the $\sum_j$ come from?  In other words, what's the proof that you can break down the left term into the sum of 3 components of the top layer (in this case).

Thanks for your help.

Link to class: https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks/lecture/gcNo6/the-backpropagation-algorithm-12-min

Comment: It's the chain rule for partial derivatives. Essentially, the derivative in the direction of a given vector is the sum of the derivatives of the components of the vector, weighted appropriately.

Comment: Hi ConMan. Thanks for your comment. I understand the chain rule. Can you explain the steps in between ? The chain rule only allows you to "slide in" one zj. Why the sum  over j ?

Comment: It's a specific version of the chain rule for functions of multiple variables (or equivalently, for functions of vectors). The following link from Khan Academy shows a demonstration (although it looks at the total derivative of the main function, and it's only applied to a 2-variable case): https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/multivariable-chain-rule/v/multivariable-chain-rule

Comment: Thanks ConMan. It starts making sense... Quick question. I see that your link refers to ordinary derivative (whereas I had a partial derivative). How do you reconcile the 2?

Comment: @ConMan It is called the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) : if $g(t) = f(x(t),y(t))$ then $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$

Comment: @GuillaumeG - I suggest you read up on the Jacobian matrix and the chain rule in higher dimensions. Essentially, the ordinary derivative applies when you've got a single underlying variable that you're differentiating with respect to, and the partial derivatives apply when you're only differentiating with respect to one variable out of many.

The Wikipedia article on the chain rule, particularly the section on higher dimensions, explains it a bit better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions

Comment: Ok perfect.Thanks @ConMan and user1952009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the multivariate chain rule. Let's assume that $E$ depends on $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$, but each $z_k$ depends on $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$, i.e.
$$ E(z(y))=E(z_1(y),\ldots,z_n(y)). $$
We are interested in how the loss objective $E$ depends on some value in an earlier layer, say the output of the $i$th node, denoted $y_i$, in layer $\xi$, but that output affects $E$ only by its influence on the *next* layer (i.e., $\xi+1$), whose values we denote $z$. 
Recall that in a fully connected network, each layer depends on all the values of the previous layer, so each $z_i$ depends on each $y_k$. 
But we only care about $y_i$ for now, meaning we can ignore the other $y_k$, because we are interested in how perturbing $y_i$ affects $E$, and $y_i$ does not affect $E$ via the other $y_k$.

But $y_i$ does affect $E$ through $z$ (and *only* through $z$ actually). 
And $y_i$ affects *every* $z_k$.
So we need to take the $\partial E / \partial z_k$ into account, as well as the $\partial z_k / \partial y_i$. 
The way to combine these into a single number is specified by the [multivariate chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions):
$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial y_i} = \sum_j  \frac{\partial E}{\partial z_j} \frac{\partial z_j}{\partial y_i}. $$
I'll add links to more formal derivations below. 
But the rough intuition is this: $E$ depends on $y_i$ through its effect on each $z_k$ (captured by $\partial z_k / \partial y_i$), so ${\partial E}/{\partial y_i}$ should be a sum of these contributions (if we think of derivatives as a measure of local linear change, we can imagine adding the perturbation vectors induced by tweaking  together). 
But not all the contributions to the network are equally important: if a $z_j$ doesn't affect $E$ much (i.e.,${\partial E}/{\partial z_j}$ is small), then the contribution of $y_i$ through $z_j$ should be down-weighted.
So we do a *weighted sum* over $\partial z_k / \partial y_i$, 
with weights given by ${\partial E}/{\partial z_j}$.
Notice that when $n=1$ we recover the classical chain rule.
For more details see the links below.

---

Other questions on the origin of the multivariate chain rule are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559724/proof-of-multivariable-chain-rule?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326429/intuition-of-multivariable-chain-rule/1326785#1326785), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566376/derivation-of-the-multivariate-chain-rule).

A related question on the role of the chain rule sum in artificial neural networks is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309311/derivatives-on-hidden-layers-in-backpropagation-anns).