# Proof of multivariable chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I'm working with a proof of the multivariable chain rule $\displaystyle{\frac{d}{dt}g(t)=\frac{df}{dx_1}\frac{dx_1}{dt}+\frac{df}{dx_2}\frac{dx_2}{dt}}$ for $g(t)=f(x_1(t),x_2(t))$, but I have a hard time understanding two important steps of this proof.

The proof includes the function $\displaystyle{\Delta_i(h)=x_i(t+h)-x_i(t)}$ for $\displaystyle{i=1,2, \bar{\Delta}=(\Delta_1(h),\Delta_2(h)) \Rightarrow \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\Delta_i}{h}=x^{'}_i}$. It says that

$\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h}=\frac{f(\bar{x}(t+h))-f(\bar{x}(t))}{h}=\frac{f(\bar{x}(t)-\bar{\Delta(h))}-f(\bar{x}(t))}{h}$

which I understand, but the next step is the to state that $f$ is differentiable and then let the previous equation be equal to

$=f^{'}_1(\bar{x}(t))\cdot\Delta_1(h)+f^{'}_2(\bar{x}(t))\cdot\Delta_2(h)+o(\vert\vert\bar{\Delta}\vert\vert)$

and this step I do not understand. I think there might be missing some limit-notation? But even with the limit notation I'm still not sure as to how it becomes a partial derivative multiplied with $\Delta_i$.

Afterwards they let $h\rightarrow0$ to get

$=f^{'}_1(\bar{x}(t))\cdot x_1^{'}(t)+f^{'}_2(\bar{x}(t))\cdot x_2^{'}(t)$

Again I am very confused as to possibly missing limit notations.

Does anyone know this version of the proof of the chain rule (besides these two steps, I find it the easiest version to understand), or understand these steps?

Here are pictures of the notes:

[Theorem: Multivariable chain rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBpHP.png)

[Proof of theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVF1P.png)

Comment: See this page regarding the "little-oh notation" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation  . Although it says Big-Oh, there is a section on little-oh on this page as well.

Comment: Actually, I see the logic behind the little-oh - it's more the products of the partial derivaties and lambda-functions that I can not see how comes up :)

Comment: Well first,this is not really a proof but an informal argument. You won't see a real proof of either single or multivariate chain rules until you take real analysis. Could you upload a picture of this for me so I can see the entire thing? Also when you say lambda do you mean delta?

Comment: Of course, sorry, I meant delta. I have now edited the question and uploaded a picture of the notes I have.

Comment: Consider that you are dealing wih: $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^n} \quad t \to f(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$$ $$g: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$$ $$\phi=g\circ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ To prove  you only have to use the definition of differtial showing that the composition is also a differential.

Comment: Take also a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJhVLmv61yE

Comment: @NKH I see someone answered. Is this to your satisfaction? You actually do need o(h)/h to go to zero. The linear algebra element he's speaking of comes from the fact that your derivatives in this context are technically matrices, and the operator norm is what allows you to force that term to 0.

Comment: @DavidReed, yes I do feel like I understand the steps now looking at my notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multivariable chain rule descends from the **theorem of composite function** for function of several variables which states in general that if:

**f and g are differentiable** in $x_0$ and $y_0=f(x_0)$, that is:

$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+J_f(x_0)\cdot h+o(|h|)$$

$$g(y_0+k)=g(y_0)+J_g(y_0)\cdot k+o(|k|)$$

The composite function $g \circ f$ is also differentiable in $x_0$ and:

$$g(f(x_0+h))=g(f(x_0))+J_g(y_0)\cdot J_f(x_0)\cdot h+o(|h|)$$

**NOTE**

For the proof it is convenient to write:

$o(|h|)=|h|\cdot \omega_f(h)$ with $\omega_f(h) \to 0$

$o(|k|)=|k|\cdot \omega_g(k)$ with $\omega_g(k) \to 0$.

In the **special case** of:

$$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^n} \quad t \to f(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$$

$$g: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$$

$$\phi=g\circ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$

we have

$$J_f(t)= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{dx_1}{d t} \\ .\\\frac{dx_n}{d t} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1' \\ .\\ x_n' \end{bmatrix}$$

$$J_g(x)= \nabla g = \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} \right)$$

> And finally:
>
> $$J_g(x)\cdot J_f(t)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}\frac{dx_1}{dt}+...+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}\frac{dx_n}{dt}$$
>
> That is the **chain rule** for this particular case.

Take also a look here: [Derivation of the multivariate chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566376/derivation-of-the-multivariate-chain-rule)

The general theorem allow to find similar rules for any case by the **Jacobian matrices** $J_f$ and $J_g$.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot actually. But I'm still unsure about the derivative of this function. We now know

$g(f(x_0+h))=g(f(x_0))+J_g(x_0)\cdot J_f(x_0)+o(\vert h\vert)$

but to take the derivative we need to write

$lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(f(x_0+h)-g(f(x_0))}{h}=lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{J_g(x_0)\cdot J_f(x_0)+o(\vert h\vert)}{h}$

I understand that little-oh can be neglected but what happens to the Jacobian matrices?

Comment: In this case to understand deeply the rule it is necessary to generalize the context. The key point is that tha differential is a linear map, thus the composition is also a linear map i.e. a product of matrices /vectors (i.e.Jacobian, Gradient).

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, I missed the h, now it's fixed!

Comment: In the proof the onlydifficult part is to show that o(|h|)/h->0.

Comment: I've added some additional note in the answer.

Comment: Fortunately, it's not required to show that $\frac{o(\vert h\vert)}{h}$ goes towards zero :D But I've looked through the proof again and now I have a much better understanding of all the steps. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: You are welcome! In multivariable calculus linear algebra plays an important role! Bye.

Answer (score 10):

These days I've been looking for a rigurous proof of the multivariable chain rule and I've finally found one that I think is very easy to understand. I will leave it here (if nobody minds) for anybody searching for this that is not familiar with little-o notation, Jacobians and stuff like this. To understand this proof, all you need to know is the mean value theorem.

Let's say we have a function $f(x,y)$ and $x = x(t), y = y(t)$. Let's also take $z(t) = f(x(t), y(t))$ By definition, the derivative of z $z'(t)$ is

$$ z'(t) = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}{\frac {f(x(t+\Delta t),y(t+\Delta t)) - f(x,y)}{\Delta t}}$$.

$$ Let \ \Delta x = x(t+\Delta t)-x(t),$$ $$\Delta y = y(t+\Delta t)-y(t)$$

Now I'll take the numerator of the fraction in the limit, and make a small change.

$$ f(x(t+\Delta t), y(t+\Delta t)) - f(x,y) = f(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y) - f(x,y)$$
$$ = \left[f(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y) - f(x+\Delta x, y)\right] + \left[f(x+\Delta x, y) - f(x, y)\right]$$

I have just added and substracted $f(x+\Delta x, y)$. For some reason, I will invert the terms.

$$ = \left[f(x+\Delta x, y) - f(x, y)\right] + \left[f(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y) - f(x+\Delta x, y)\right]$$.

Now, let's define 2 functions and I will name them g and h. First,

$$ Let \ g(x) = f(x, y) \implies g'(x) = \frac {\partial f} {\partial x} $$.

Please note that y is constant here since g is a function of a single variable. Now, by the mean value theorem we have

$$ \exists c_1 \in (x, x+\Delta x) \ so \ that$$
$$\frac {g(x+\Delta x) - g(x)} {\Delta x} = g'(c_1) $$
$$ \Longleftrightarrow $$
$$ f(x+\Delta x, y) - f(x, y) = f_x(c_1, y)\Delta x$$

Similarly, using the function
$$ h(y) = f(x + \Delta x, y) \implies h'(y) = \frac {\partial} {\partial y}f(x+\Delta x, y)$$

We will have by the same logic that

$$ f(x+\Delta x, y + \Delta y) -  f(x+\Delta x, y) = 
f_y(x + \Delta x, c_2)\Delta y, c_2 \in (y, y+\Delta y) $$

Notice that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are bounded with respect to $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$
So as $\Delta x \to 0, c_1 \to x$ and as $\Delta y \to 0, c_2 \to y$. By our definition of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$, as $\Delta t \to 0$, both $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ $\to 0$. So, as $\Delta t \to 0$, $c_1 \to x$ and $c_2 \to y$.

The last step of the proof is to sum this all up, divide by $\Delta t$ and take the limit as $\Delta t \to 0$

$$ f(x(t+\Delta t), y(t+\Delta t)) - f(x, y) = f_x(c_1, y)\Delta x + f_y(x+\Delta x, c_2)\Delta y $$
$$ \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac {f(x(t+\Delta t), y(t+\Delta t))}{\Delta t} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} f_x(c_1, y)\frac {\Delta x}{\Delta t} + f_y(x+\Delta x, c_2)\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta t} = f_x(x, y)x'(t) + f_y(x, y)y'(t) \ QED $$

**Edit:** After a long time I've realised that this proof assumes that $f$ has partial derivatives defined on intervals around the point $(x, y)$ and they are continuous at the point. This is a sufficient condition for the function to be ($\mathbb{R}^2$-)differentiable at $(x, y)$, but it's not equivalent. Yet, the multivariable chain rule works for the function being just differentiable at that point. So for a general proof, one should first understand little-o notation as in the other answers.

Comment: Can you use this to prove for more than 2 variables?

Comment: Yes, this generalises fairly easily to the multivariable chain rule: for a function $f({\bf x})$ where ${\bf x}$ is an n-dimensional vector, $\frac{d}{dt} f({\bf x}(t)) = \nabla f({\bf x}(t)) \cdot {\bf x}'(t)$

Comment: Very straightforward, yet rigorous proof. One small modification I would do is defining $c_i$ as $c_i = \theta_ix + (1-\theta_i)\Delta x$ for some $\theta_i\in(0,1)$. This way you make sure that the negative case is automatically covered. Also, curious whether this proof also covers the cases where e.g. $\Delta x$ rapidly takes value of $0$ close to the limit point, such as when $x(t) = x^2\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: @Viktorio El Hakim  Both issues can be covered (I think) by letting $c_1 = \left\{\begin{align*}&x + (1-\theta_1)\Delta x & \Delta x \ne 0 \\ &x & \Delta x = 0 \end{align*}\right.$ This way, $g(x+\Delta x) - g(x) = g'(c_1)\Delta x$ is still true, MVT covering the first branch and $0 = 0$ the second one, and $\lim_{t\to 0} c_1(t) = x$. I'm not sure if there are any flaws to this, thanks for pointing those out.